# HaarTraining: doing stage 0 again and txt file

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

What does it mean when Haar training finishes stage 0, outputs a txt file and no .xml and decides to perform stage 0 again?

Thank you

By the way: this may be related to another one of my posts where I was having issues with opencv_traincascade, so I decided to use haartraining and this happened: [Haar Training: error (-215)_img.row * _img.cols == vecSize in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726973/haar-training-error-215-img-row-img-cols-vecsize-in-function)

---

Here are the responses from one Haar training execution. It finishes stage 0 and then starts again as shown below:

---

First Stage 0

```
Number of features used : 3951220

Parent node: NULL

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 2000 2000 1.000000
NEG: 2000 1
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.342012| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.276750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.527221| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.265750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3|100%|-|-0.691320| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.249750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   4| 85%|+|-0.824964| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.225000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   5| 91%|-|-1.065741| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.207000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   6| 85%|+|-1.199052| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.192500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   7| 85%|-|-1.348132| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.180000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   8| 91%|+|-1.410564| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.179000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   9| 88%|-|-1.158043| 0.997000| 0.810500| 0.162000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  10| 80%|+|-1.249312| 0.996000| 0.769000| 0.160750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  11| 79%|-|-1.386396| 0.997000| 0.777000| 0.145250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  12| 78%|+|-1.388796| 0.996000| 0.687000| 0.144500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  13| 78%|-|-1.338245| 0.996000| 0.724000| 0.139000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  14| 77%|+|-1.275169| 0.995500| 0.672500| 0.138000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  15| 76%|-|-1.414586| 0.996000| 0.698500| 0.127000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  16| 76%|+|-1.484858| 0.995500| 0.616500| 0.121250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  17| 75%|-|-1.545480| 0.996000| 0.591500| 0.113750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  18| 73%|+|-1.519740| 0.995500| 0.585000| 0.111250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  19| 73%|-|-1.434103| 0.995500| 0.527500| 0.105750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  20| 72%|+|-1.475413| 0.995500| 0.536000| 0.105750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  21| 72%|-|-1.503680| 0.995500| 0.537500| 0.102500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  22| 71%|+|-1.521223| 0.995500| 0.529000| 0.096000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  23| 71%|-|-1.496952| 0.995500| 0.484000| 0.089250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 49991.00
Number of used features: 23
```

Second Stage 0 in progress :

```
Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+
|  0|
+---+

   0


Parent node: 0

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 2000 2009 0.995520
NEG: 2000 0.517464
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.224272| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.332750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.268457| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.303750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3| 97%|-|-0.381251| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.262000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   4| 93%|+|-0.683000| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.264750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   5| 93%|-|-0.935299| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.263750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   6| 87%|+|-1.005094| 0.998000| 0.965500| 0.270000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   7| 86%|-|-1.095243| 0.998000| 0.967500| 0.244500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   8| 84%|+|-1.152430| 0.998000| 0.968500| 0.233750|
+
```